# Logging current draw over time, 100mA +

Tags: raspberry-pi, current-measurement, datalogger

What is a good way to log(sample) current draw over a period of time, from e.g a RaspberryPi with some equipment connected to it (100 mA +).

A datalogger like the EasyLog | EL-USB-4 have a measurement range of 4-20mA d.c. Is there a smart way to use it to log higher currents?

Comment: No there is no smart way, there might be but that depends on the design (circuit) of the datalogger which I do not have. You could use the EL-USB-3 instead which is a **Voltage** datalogger. Then feed the current you want to measure through a resistor and measure the voltage drop across that resistor using Ohm's law.

Comment: Presuming that you're powering the Pi over USB, you can buy cheap USB dongles that monitor voltage and current, and accumulated mAh. Google **usb power meter** and see what you find.

Comment: A small shunt resistor on the power line, and an Arduino reading the shunt and printing to the console with voltage and current readings. You can then add them up in Excel etc.

Comment: You should be able to add a shunt across that EasyLog to get it to measure higher current. Have you looked into that?